# celery: Break loop in task

Tags: python, celery, fastapi

I have a FastAPI app and integrated celery with Redis. It will be a "ping-like" application.
I want API endpoints to start and stop a given task.

My task is basically a "ping" probe, which is executed inside an endless while loop:

```py
@app.task
def tcp_ping(target_host: str):
  success_count = 0
  fail_count = 0
  while not interrupted:
    # someCode which does the probing (pinging)
    if success:
      success_count += 1
    else:
      fail_count += 1
    sleep(100)

  result = {
    "success": success_count,
    "failures": fail_count
  }
  return result
```

If I would not use Celery and if this would be an interactive application, I would add a signal handler, which changes the variable `interrupted` to `True`, the loop exits and the results are presented.

Is there any good way to solve this using Celery?

I have not found any examples for my special use case.
I'm aware, that this is not "best practice" and tasks should be finite. But for my use-case the loop within the task must run infinitely instead of queuing the task in a given interval.